# How to force macOS finder to connect to server through AFP rather than SMB?

Tags: macos

While a server offers both AFP and SMB the finder chooses SMB as default since 10.11 I believe...

...is there a know defaults param to force the finder to connect through AFP?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the terminal command line or the finder's "connect to" option. Both allow you to specify the protocol:

Terminal:

> afp://user:pass@ipaddress/SharedDrive /Volumes/mount

Finder:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer TomEus.

I haven't been enough precise: I would like say to force the Finder browser to connect through AFP.

Comment: I don't think that is an option, that change was done in Maverick and as far as I know the above are the only options